# ipv6 route slightly modified

Tags: linux, ipv6, route, loopback

I am running GNU/Linux version 3.4.113+ with a 6in4 tunnel to a tunnel broker. If I run command

```
ip -6 route list table local
```

I see a lot of routes. And one of this route entries is this

```
local ::1 via :: dev lo  proto none  metric 0
```

This is the situation after a reboot of the server for several hours. Under certain circumstances this entry changes to this

```
local ::1 via :: dev lo  proto none  metric 0  rtt 18ms rttvar 15ms cwnd 10
```

Till now I couldn't figure out why. Are there any ideas what could cause this change ?

Comment: Those looks like they may be stats recorded by TCP in order to improve performance. But 18ms round trip time to localhost sounds like too much.

Answer (score 0):

After days of looking into logs and analyzing I found the reason. I am using a reverse SSH tunnel on this server. But this doesn't happen if the tunnel is opened. It happens if the tunnel is used actively the first time. As I am not always using this tunnel it took a while until I found the reason.